# Way to identify how many rows got updated from logs

Tags: sql, sql-server, trace, error-log, dmv

We process CSV files from our upstream systems and load them to our master tables in our SQL Server database. We are currently on boarding a new upstream system and suddenly our UPDATE statement took very long time. It could be due to incoming data having previous related data in our system and it caused huge update. We are able to find out the table which was getting updated through `sp_whoisactive`.

My query is:

- **Post the update**, is there a way to figure out the number of rows updated for the table from some place like error log or default trace or through DMV?
- **During update**, if we find these kind of huge update happening in future, can we set up some trace to identify the number of rows will get updated or figure out the update statement with current parameters (current values of parameters) ? In `sp_whoisactive` we get update statement with variables. But we don't know the current parameters.
- **Proactively**, should we setup extended events or something else to capture these kinds of huge updates in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your third question first. Yes. If you really want to track specific values for changes, the best way to do this is through Extended Events and you must set it up and have it running ahead of time. As you'll see in the rest of this post, there may be no easy way to retrieve the specific information you're looking for, depending. Something like sql_statement_completed will give you precise row counts for a given event. You can filter it to a specific table.

Second question, during updates, you can't really see how many rows are being updated accurately within a transaction. However, you can get a guess at how many rows are likely to be updated. The execution plan will have the row estimates that it anticipates will occur. So, you can query this from sys.dm_exec_query_plan. Combine it with sys.dm_exec_sql_batch to find the query. I'm sure sp_whoisactive can also supply this information (it's just querying the DMVs). You can also watch [Live Query Statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/live-query-statistics?view=sql-server-ver15) if you've set your server up correctly ahead of time. That will give you the estimated row counts, but then it will show you the actuals as they occur.

Now for the tough question. Can you get row counts after the fact? Kind of. If the query just executed and hasn't executed again, sys.dm_exec_sql_batch does have a last_rows column that will provide that info. If more than one query has run though, that information is lost because it's only the most recent execution of the query. If you're on Azure SQL Database, or SQL Server 2019, you can also [look to sys.dm_exec_query_plan_stats](https://www.scarydba.com/2019/09/09/get-the-last-actual-plan-with-sys-dm_exec_query_plan_stats/) to see the last Execution Plan Plus Runtime Metrics. That will also have row counts Although, if that's all you're looking for, and this is the most recent execution, the batch DMV is easier. I don't know if that column is included in sp_whoisactive, but you can just query the DMV yourself.

However, if the query has run more than once, you're out of luck. You can look to the execution plan, as was mentioned before, to see what the row estimates are. If the query suffered from waits more than 30 seconds, it will show up in the system_health extended event session, but that won't include row counts. Really, unless it's the very last time the exact query was run, there's no way after the fact to get the row count value.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Very insightful. I will utilize the query plan based metrics to figure out the rows affected. Again, thanks for taking time to answer.